# Cannot access website after installing SSL cerificate

Tags: node.js, linux, nginx, reverse-proxy

I am using Nuxt.js for my projekt with a reverse proxy.

My code without SSL was this here:

```
server {
   server_name mywebsite.at;
   location / {
      proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
      proxy_http_version 1.1;
      proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
      proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
   }
}
```

Everything works very well here, but after installing an SSL certificate with certbot i cant access my webpage. I get always an 404 error.

```
server {
    server_name mywebsite.at;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
     }
     location /socket.io/ {
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000/socket.io/;
     }

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/mywebsite.at/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/mywebsite.at/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}
server {
    if ($host = mywebsite.at) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    listen 80;
    server_name mywebsite.at;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot


}
```

I cant figure the issue here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the issue. port `443` was blocked by the firewall. `ufw allow 443` fixed the issue

Answer (score 1):

I think you have a conflicting configuration there. Try removing the

```
listen 80;
```

If that doesnt work, try replacing it with

```
listen 443;
```

Let me know what it gives

Answer (score 0):

Try test if port 443 is open running `ss -ntpl|grep :443`, if the port appears in results, You can test from outside running telnet or nc command from another location.

`telnet mywebsite.at 443`

or

`nc -vz -w 1 mywebsite.at 443` # You'll need to install nc before running

Maybe you

Comment: i have already fixed it. 443 was closed `ufw allow 443` fixed the issue